# Irreducible Representations Definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, definition

I'm currently reading a book which is quite simple until now who tried to define irreps as:

> "If by one and the same equivalence transformation, all the
> matrices in the representation of a group can be made to acquire the same block form, then the representation is said to be reducible; otherwise it is irreducible. Thus, an irreducible representation cannot be expressed in terms of representations of lower dimensionality."

But the simple one dimensional matrix (1) can be a representation to all groups, and easily be converted to have the same block form for all. Clearly it is not a reducible representation. How is that working out with the book definition?

Here is an image from the page:

> [image]

---

**EDIT**
The textbook is [Group Theory : Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/L4u0cQAACAAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY5sLWiKr4AhVO7HMBHRvlBrwQre8FegQIFxAG) By Mildred S. Dresselhaus, Gene Dresselhaus, Ado Jorio. Definition is on `Page 17`.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which book is that?

Comment: Doesn't the book say a word about stable subspaces? A representation is in terms of linear maps, not matrices, there's a caveat to just using those...

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. It has not defined subspaces yet and I don't remember the definition. The book is called "Group Theory application to the physics of condensed matter" by Mildred S. Dresselhaus.  This definition is only in page 17

Comment: You need to check what the author means by "block form". I am guessing that it means a nontrivial decomposition i.e. into more than one block. Otherwsie every representation would be in block form without doing anything.

Comment: @DerekHolt What you are saying sounds right, but the funny thing is that he uses the block form definition in the same page, I'll add the image in the question.

Comment: The definition in the book is flacky, but linear representations are irreducible by that definition, the block in this case is just a single element (a $1 \times 1$ matrix if you will).

Comment: What I meant is that given your representation $\rho:G\to GL(V)$, say that $\rho$ is **reducible** if there exists a (non-zero and non-total) subspace $W<V$ such that $W$ is stable under each $\rho(g)$. This implies that in a basis adapted to a decomposition $V=W\oplus X$, each matrices have a block-diagonal form. Does that help?

Comment: (*Note:* a stable supplement $X$ is guaranteed to exist by Maschke.)

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Thanks for the help kind of. At that point of the book the term subspace ain't defined. but yeah kind of help.